NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element: If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module
I'm encountering an error when trying to run ng serve or ng build. The error message states: 'router-outlet' is not a known element. Here's the structure of my Angular application:
app.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './features/features.component';
import { HowItWorksComponent } from './how-it-works/how-it-works.component';
import { UploadComponent } from './upload/upload.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomepageComponent,
    FeaturesComponent,
    HowItWorksComponent,
    UploadComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]), // Import RouterModule.forRoot with an empty array
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

app-routing.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './features/features.component';
import { HowItWorksComponent } from './how-it-works/how-it-works.component';
import { UploadComponent } from './upload/upload.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent },
  { path: 'features', component: FeaturesComponent },
  { path: 'how-it-works', component: HowItWorksComponent },
  { path: 'upload', component: UploadComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

app.component.html:
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

app.component.ts:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'mri-scan-analyzer';
}


I've been stuck on this error for a few hours now and none of the solutions I found on StackOverflow seem to work for me. I suspect it could be related to the order of imports in my app.module.ts file, but I'm relatively new to Angular and would appreciate any help.

which version of angular? Please remove the import of routermodule in app.module, you are already doing that from AppRoutingModule. It is wrong anyway

Removed routermodule in import, angular 17.3.3 latest one

I don't think there is anything wrong with the code you shared except that you should remove RouterModule.forRoot([]), because your AppRoutingModule already exports that.

it still says router outlet is not a known element even after removing that, any suggestions?

You have already included RouterModule as a part of AppRoutingModule so kindly remove the below line!
 ...
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    // RouterModule.forRoot([]), // not needed!
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  ...


Please use this working example from stackblitz download it and copy paste your components along with the routing, it will solve your issue!
Blank Angular modular project

doesn't change anything mate, I added that to check if it works with it, removing doesn't do anything

tried, doesn't seem to work, same error as before

@Heisenberg Share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated
